# is it possible to use radio list tile created from a for loop to out put and select data from a constructor in flutter

Tags: flutter

this the constructor I made

```
    class User {

     String strength1;
     String strength2;
     String strength3;
     String strength4;
     String strength5;

     User({this.strength1, this.strength2, this.strength3,this.strength4,this.strength5});

     Map<String, dynamic>toMap(){
     var map = <String, dynamic>{
     'strength1' : strength1,
     'strength2' : strength2,
     'strength3' : strength3,
     'strength4' : strength4,
     'strength5' : strength5,
      };
     return map;
    }
    User.fromMap(Map <String, dynamic>map){
     strength1 = map['strength1'];
     strength2 = map['strength2'];
     strength3 = map['strength3'];
     strength4 = map['strength4'];
     strength5 = map['strength5'];
   }

  }
```

and then the loop should be

```
      List<Widget> createRadioListUsers() {
  List<Widget>widgets = [];
  for (User user in users) {
    widgets.add(
      RadioListTile(
        value: user,
        groupValue: selectedUser,
        title: Text(user.strengths),
        onChanged: (currentUser) {
          print('Current User ${currentUser.strengths}');

          setSelectedUser(currentUser);
        },
        selected: selectedUser == user,
        activeColor: Colors.green,
       
    );
  }
  return widgets;
}
```

I learned this loop from a tutorial and tried changing the type of constructor but apparently the values for the radio button won't work since in the tutorial the values were already given but for the program I'm making I have to get the user input from another page to this page and show them in a radio list tile

Comment: so an update I made an int id1-5 in User and made an int id 1-5. now when I press 1 radio button everything is selected

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using StreamBuilder:

**First, let's declare the controller, the stream and getter**

```
final BehaviorSubject<User> _radioController = BehaviorSubject<User>();
Stream<User> get radioStream => _radioController.stream;
Function(User) get updateRadio => _radioController.sink.add;
```

**Then, put the builder in your widget**

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: radioStream,
      initialData: null,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
for (User user in users) {
    widgets.add(
      RadioListTile(
        value: user,
        groupValue: snapshot.data, // The value will be updated when you select an other radio
        title: Text(user.strengths),
        onChanged: updateRadio, // Update the groupValue
        selected: selectedUser == user,
        activeColor: Colors.green,
       
    );
  },
  // Return your widgets, for example Column(children: widgets),
},
),
...
```

Comment: BehaviorSubject is keyword or should I enter something like List or etc?

Comment: I use BehaviorSubject but it's just a kind StreamController. You can get it by getting the package rxdart, or just use a StreamController.